# iOS: unable to logout Facebook user and ask for email and password again

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm having trouble switching users once I log in for the first time. I tried using

```
loginManager.logOut
```

But I keep getting returned to the same screen with no option to log out. How do I make it so it asks me for email and password again?

[image]

Comment: Using Swift Cocoapods 5.5.0 Same issue...Have you find any solutions yes?? @ MXV

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **another** solution. Change the login behaviour of loginManager like so

```
 let loginManager = LoginManager()
 loginManager.loginBehavior = .browser
```

It will open webview prompting for username and password each time when user logs out.

Then log in the user using the code

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self, completion: { (loginResult) in

    switch loginResult {
    case .failed(let error):
      print(error)
    case .cancelled:
      print("User cancelled login.")
    case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
      print(grantedPermissions)
      print(declinedPermissions)
      print(accessToken)
      print("Logged in!")

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login;  //Global object for same class

login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init]; //when tap on login with Facebook


// for logout
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
[login logOut];
```